# OpenGL scene rendering as black with shadow mapping

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shadow-mapping

I am trying to implement shadow mapping in my OpenGL engine using this tutorial : http://www.fabiensanglard.net/shadowmapping/index.php

I don't have any problems while making the shadow map (i think ). But using it the scene is totally shadowed.

The way I am rendering my scene is as follows:

- ### Set up the depth FBO

  ```
  GLuint sdepthtex;
  GLuint sframebuffer ;

  glGenTextures(1, &sdepthtex);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sdepthtex);

  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 1024, 1024, 0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);

  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, sdepthtex, 0);

  glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
  glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

  if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
  {
   displayMessage("Error loading the Depth Framebuffer");
   return;
  }
  ```
- ### Make the ModelViewProjection matrix from light's perspective and store it in a shadowMatrix variable.

The function i use :

```
Matrix getMVPmatrix(vector3 position,vector3 lookat )
{

 glPushMatrix();

 double projection[16];
 double modelView[16];
 SDL_Surface*screen = SDL_GetVideoSurface();

 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluPerspective(FOVY,screen->w/screen->h,NEAR,FAR);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluLookAt(position.x,position.y,position.z,lookat.x,lookat.y,lookat.z,0,1,0);

 glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelView);
 glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);

 Matrix m1(projection);
 Matrix m2(modelView);

 glPopMatrix();

 return m1*m2;

}
```

- ### Render the scene in the depth framebuffer. The shaders :

Vertex Shader:

```
uniform mat4 shadowMatrix;

void main()
{

    gl_Position = shadowMatrix*gl_Vertex;  

}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
void main(void)
{

    gl_FragDepth = gl_FragCoord.z;

}
```

For my 3 boxes scene, the linearized depth look like this :

http://www.2shared.com/photo/IExy9aUo/Depth.html

So i think the shadowMatrix and the depth rendering are right.

- ### The last pass is just about drawing the scene with the shadow map

Vertex Shader:

```
varying vec4 ShadowCoord;
uniform mat4 shadowMatrix;

mat4 biasMatrix = mat4(
0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0
);

void main (void)
{
    gl_TexCoord[0] =  gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    ShadowCoord = biasMatrix*shadowMatrix *vec4(gl_Vertex.xyz,1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D shadowtex;//the non linearized depth texture we made in the 3rd step.
varying vec4 ShadowCoord;

float getShadowFactor(void)
{
    vec4 shadowCoordinateWdivide = ShadowCoord / ShadowCoord.w ;

    shadowCoordinateWdivide.z += 0.0005;

    float distanceFromLight = texture2D(shadowtex,shadowCoordinateWdivide.st).z;

    float shadow = 1.0;
    if (ShadowCoord.w > 0.0)
        shadow = distanceFromLight < shadowCoordinateWdivide.z ? 0.5 :1.0 ;

    return shadow ;

}

void main (void)
{

    gl_FragColor =texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].st);

    gl_FragColor.rgb *= getShadowFactor() ;//add shadows Here

}
```

### The result ? all my scene is shadowed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code has an inconsistency between the texture setup and the shader. In the texture setup code, you have this:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);
```

When `GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC` is not `GL_NONE`, you need to use a shadow texture sampler in your shader code. But in your fragment shader, you use a regular sampler for this texture:

```
uniform sampler2D shadowtex;
```

This needs to be changed to this to be compatible with the texture settings:

```
uniform sampler2DShadow shadowtex;
```

To match the type, `shadow2D()` is then used instead of `texture2D()` to sample the texture.

The other option is that you keep `GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC` at its default value of `GL_NONE`. This is then consistent with using a `sampler2D` for sampling.

Comment: Yes ! i finally switched to sampler2DShadow.
To get a shadow value i use :
shadow2D( shadowMap, ShadowCoord.xyz / ShadowCoord.w).r;